# Flutter ScrollablePositionedList causing exception

Tags: android, ios, flutter, scroll

I am fairly new to Flutter. I'm working on an app that needs to preserve scroll position in a ListView when users navigate to and from the ListView. I am attempting to use ScrollablePositionedList to accomplish this. I have followed the simple example provided by Google and am getting an error when calling `jumpTo` on my `ItemScrollController`.

My ListView is built from downloaded JSON so I am using a FutureBuilder to initially construct and cache the list view item models.

Here is an excerpt from my code:

```
  var listener = ItemPositionsListener.create();
  var scroller = ItemScrollController();

  ScrollablePositionedList _listView(
      AsyncSnapshot snapshot, BuildContext context) {

var list = ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Text(snapshot.data[index].gaugeName),
    );
  },
  itemPositionsListener: listener,
  itemScrollController: scroller,
);

scroller.jumpTo(index: 100); // error here
return list;
}


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _getFavorites();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(kAllStates[widget.stateAbbreviation]),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _getGaugesForState(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return _listView(snapshot, context);
          } else {
            return Align(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      endDrawer: RFDrawer(),
    );
  }
}
```

When `scroller.jumpTo(index: 100);` is called, I get the following error:

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method '_jumpTo' was called on null.
Receiver: null
```

[image]

Does anyone have any clues as to what might be causing this error, or what I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure and correct me if I'm wrong but are you confident that you get 100 items from the API? so I guess you're jumping to an index that doesn't exist. Another guess is that you're trying to jump to an index before the ListView is built, so I guess you can return the list, then use a button to scroll to the specific index or a Timer object to auto-scroll after some time passes to make sure the ListView is fully built.

Also if you want to preserve the scroll offset or position while navigating to different pages, like you have a navigation bar with different tabs, one of them has a ListView and you want to preserve the scroll position while navigating, so I assume [PageStorageKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageStorageKey-class.html) is a good option to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Though I can't figure out your entire codes and approaches but it help me a lot. The side note is that your problem is very simple. You want to jump the index of list before creating the list itself.

```
scroller.jumpTo(index: 100); // remove this line from here
return list;
```

What you have to do that, After returning the list and make sure and check that your desired index item is populated or exist, then create and call another method to `jumpTo` the index.